# Particular solution to Laplace equation in polar coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Using Separation of variables for $\nabla^2 u$ in polar coordinates I got to the general solution:

$$u(r,\theta)=A_0 + B_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \left( A_nr^n+C_nr^{-n} \right)cos(n\theta) + \left( B_nr^n+D_nr^{-n} \right)sin(n\theta) \right] $$

and I have the initial condition $u(a,\theta)=0$

My question is that, if given the general solution can just assume that, due to the divergencies at $r=0$ and $r\rightarrow \infty$ , $ B_0=C_n=D_n=0 $ ? Then:
$$ u(r,\theta)=A_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[A_nr^ncos(n\theta)+B_nsin(n\theta)\right]$$

and use Fourier integrals to find the coefficients.

If not, I evaluate in r=a, then:

$$u(a,\theta)=0=A_0 + B_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \left( A_na^n+C_na^{-n} \right)cos(n\theta) + \left( B_na^n+D_na^{-n} \right)sin(n\theta) \right] $$
but how do I proceed from there?

Comment: If you have no demands on convergence on $r \to 0$ and $r \to \infty$, you should have an annulus. In which case you have two boundary conditions at the inner and outer radius,

Comment: According to the problem I have a disc and the only boundary condition is $u(a,\theta)=0$, but nothing is said for $r\rightarrow 0$ nor $r\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Ah, because it's a disc, you know that you can throw out the C and D terms. If it is well defined on the disc means it is well defined at $r=0$. Also you should combine $A_0+B_0$ into one constant.

Comment: So it becomes a matter of finding the Fourier coefficients then?

Comment: Yes. But since it was $u(a,\theta)=0$, you could have solved it much quicker.

Comment: One last thing, if $n \rightarrow \infty$ then my solution diverges in $r^n$ shouldn't $A_n$ and $B_n$ be the terms that must be zero?
$C_n$ and $D_n$ are the ones multiplied by $r^{-n}$ and, eventually, that will sum nothing (then converging to something)

Comment: No, those would vanish if you wanted it to extend to $r \to \infty$, but you don't. It's just a disc. However, they must have enough decay properties with n so that you get convergence at $r=a$.